# Is it safe to call an untrusted service with jquery.ajax and dataType 'jsonp'

Tags: web-browser, xss, javascript, html, jsonp

From what I understand, the [JSON-P](http://bob.ippoli.to/archives/2005/12/05/remote-json-jsonp/) technique generates a script tag into the DOM of an HTML page to get across the single-origin restrictions imposed on the XMLHttpRequest JavaScript API for AJAX calls to web services not supporting [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Usually, the script embedded in this way only contains a callback and in this way transfers the JSON payload that I'm interested in. However, AFAIK the called JSON-P service could also deliver arbitrary JavaScript and in this way hijack my webpage.

I'm wondering if I really have to trust the JSON-P service provider not to do this? Or do JavaScript libraries and/or browsers [sanitize the JSON-P responses](http://json-p.org/) and in this way prevent these kind of attacks?

For example for the [JQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function, the use of JSON-P is enabled by setting the rather harmlessly looking attribute `dataType: 'jsonp'` - so maybe these kind of calls are not as bad as I think they are?

Comment: json-p is essentially XSSing yourself, and I honestly wouldn't be surprised if the browsers shut it down in the future.
If you want to use an external api, don't even subdomain them, just do mydomain.com/facebook/ and redirect that route to the service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No** it is not safe. You are correct that the JSONP service could deliver arbitrary JavaScript, which is then executed as part of your site.

Because JSONP is essentially a hack to get around the same origin policy, it is not possible for a JavaScript framework to perform sanitisation.

These days, CORS is the preferred way to call external sites. An alternative approach is to have a server-side script on your site that proxies calls to external sites.